# How to keep MinIO backed up?

Tags: backup, amazon-s3

We're running MinIO internally for object storage. Ideally, we'd like to be able to do backups the same way that would with other important data. Ideally, we'd like to be able to take snapshots hourly, nightly, weekly with rotation rules about how long to keep each.

While I know about mc mirror or rsync sort of backup solutions, those are really there to give you a mirror copy of your data, that isn't as helpful to prevent accidental deletions or say if you corrupted an object by accident.

Answer (score 2):

So I had a quick play around with MinIO and it looks like it
simply stores it's data on the local filesystem.  But if you start it with docker, you're going to have the data end up inside the container filesystem.  So I'd recommend you create a data container and backup from that container, or simply bind mount to the host.

Then, you can use any tool that does regular backups style backups.

A very lightweight one based on rsync is [rsnapshot](http://rsnapshot.org/)?  It uses rsync but doesn't mirror deletions and stuff.  And you get an optimal difference backup at the other end.

Otherwise the more traditional backup software like [bacula](http://bacula.org/) would work well.  I have a friend who uses that and swears by it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm going to try this out. My concern with file-based backup solutions is whether I need to take cold backups (i.e. shutdown MinIO prior to taking the backup). I'm also concerned that if you use MinIO in distributed mode (erasure coding) you'd have to coordinate backups.

Comment: Test it on your desktop? Hopefully the files are written atomically.

Comment: @SeafoodBuffet Any update from your testing? Did you need to take cold backups?

Comment: Hi there, sorry for not updating this. I spoke with the MinIO developers and you absolutely need to do a cold backup because there's no guarantee of consistency at the filesystem level while the MinIO server is running. What they had suggested as an alternative is to have a separate (doesn't have to be highly redundant) installation of MinIO and then use the mc CLI to sync from your active instance to your backup. Keep in mind this is roughly 18-month old information at this point. It's possible things have changed and there's better solutions that exist for this.